# How can I show scheduled alerts with custom snooze/Ok button on ios with swift

Tags: ios

How can I show scheduled alerts in iOS when my application is not running in foreground / background ?

**For example**: like the alerts that ask for iOS update

If it's possible, then can I add custom buttons to it (snooze button) ?

Comment: [Read the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/).

Comment: As I said in my question "When my application is not running at all"

Comment: http://www.appcoda.com/local-notifications-ios8/

Comment: Thank you so much @Paulw11 , this is what I was looking for, I read about local notifications before but I thought that all they do is to show messages in the notification bar